# What is the reason behind popup opening only first time

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, jquery

I have a strange problem and i m not able to understand why it is happening.

I called a page - Remarks(say) by jquery ajax on row click of grid viw. Then i binded that page (coming in response) into a div - dvRemarks(say). This div is opening in a popup.

Pop-up window is only opening first time, which is working fine. But when i click second time, data is coming in response, But this time popup is not opening. Problem is with popup only but i don't understand why it is ?

When i again refresh the page, it again opens up Ist time only.

Below is jquery :-

```
jQuery(function() {
            // Remarks          
            jQuery('#<%=dvRemarks1.ClientID %>').dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                width: 600,
                modal: true
            });
            // Remarks Link
            jQuery('#lnkDialog').click(function() {
                jQuery('#<%=dvRemarks1.ClientID %>').dialog('open');
                return false;
            });
         });
```

Below is the function which i am calling on click :-

```
function Call_Ajax(id)
    {   
        var d = new Date();
        var n = d.getMilliseconds();
        var parameters="id=" + id;
                $.ajax({
                      type: "POST",
                      url: "Remark.aspx",
                      data: {id:id, n:n},
                      success: function(response) {
                            $('#<%=dvRemarks.ClientID %>').html(response);
                            $("#lnkDialog").click();
                        },
                        error: function() {
                            alert('Some problem has been occured.');
                        }
                 });
     }
```

And below is the div - dvRemarks in which i am binding response

```
<div id="dvRemarks1" runat="server" style="display: none;" title="Enter Remarks">
        <div id="dvRemarks" runat="server">
        </div>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have it inside UpdatePanel ?

Comment: No dear i haven't placed it inside update panel

Comment: I tried that also but it's doesn't solves my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure on this but give a try to below one.

```
jQuery(function() {
        // Remarks          
        jQuery('#<%=dvRemarks1.ClientID %>').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 600,
            modal: true,  //Calling destroy on close function might help
            close: function() {
                        $(this).dialog("destroy");
                }
        });
        // Remarks Link
        jQuery('#lnkDialog').click(function() {
            jQuery('#<%=dvRemarks1.ClientID %>').dialog('open');
            return false;
        });
     });
```

give a try changing ajax call to

```
function Call_Ajax(id)
{   
    var d = new Date();
    var n = d.getMilliseconds();
    var parameters="id=" + id;
            $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: "Remark.aspx",
                  data: {id:id, n:n},
                  success: function(response) {
                        $('#<%=dvRemarks.ClientID %>').empty().html(response); //empty function may be of some help here
                        $("#lnkDialog").click();
                    },
                    error: function() {
                        alert('Some problem has been occured.');
                    }
             });
 }
```

Comment: No, i tried this one.But it's not working..But anyways thanks.

Comment: I am not able to understand that if i disable this popup, then everything is working fine(response is coming). And then how it is working first time. Is there anything wrong with ajax response..?

Comment: But it is coming same response. But what happens second time ?

Comment: If it is working Ist time then it should work for IInd time also..Is there any cache issue or something else..?

Comment: Dear Pratik, this is giving error - Error: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'destroy'

Comment: As per i know for the first time click its actually `(initialize + click)` And for initilize the whole dailog box is executed and click event is suprresed.

Comment: I want to tell you one more thing that the page i am binding from response, contains html controls, not asp controls. And if i would use asp controls then it is working fine.But that creates some other issues thats why i used html controls.